# How Can I Solve Laravel Lumen Error / JWT Secret Is Not Set?

Tags: php, jwt, lumen

I would like to use JWT at Laravel Lumen for using Bearer token at authentication of user. But I'm getting an error at postman for the login endpoint. How can I solve this problem? Can you give me an idea?

```
class AuthenticateController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'refresh', 'logout']]);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);

        if (! $token = Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add JWT_SECRET to your .env file

Comment: Thank you @Anton, laravel automatically created JWT_SECRET when running 'php artisan jwt:secret' commands. I solved the problem with added method like below to Controller.php. cController extends BaseController
{
    public function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => null
        ], 200);
    }
}